# ClassNotFoundException gets thrown with DriverManger.getConnection?

Tags: java, jdbc, classnotfoundexception

Would like to know whether or not potentially the `ClassNotFoundException` could be get thrown in the following scenario:

```
DriverManager.getConnection(...);
```

I know it could be get thrown when loading manually the drivers `Class.forName(drivers..)` on the other hand from JDBC 4.0 onwards there is no need of doing it manually as class DriverManager automatically does the job.
My question is: when automatically loading the drivers, if not found the right driver, does it throws the `ClassNotFoundException`? I see in the API of DriverManager it throws only SQLException and it's not related in anyhow to ClassNotFoundException.

Does it mean it won't throw it?
Thanks,

Indeed ItIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it could not throw `ClassNotFoundException`. With JDBC4, if the `Driver` isn't registered, you'll just get an exception stating that no registered driver exists for that url. Something like

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for <your url>
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at ru.expbrain.flib.Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

The javadoc for `DriverManager.getConnection(String)` states

> The DriverManager attempts to select an appropriate driver from the
>   set of registered JDBC drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Its the Class.forName method that throws `ClassNotFoundExceptionhttp` not  DriverManager.getConnection(...). See [forName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) documentation.

Also make sure that that you provided the fully qualified class name as class.forName() expects a fully qualified class name

Answer (score 0):

It throws SQLException, something like  `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test`. It is stated in DriverManager.getConnection API

```
Throws: SQLException - if a database access error occurs
```

Answer (score 0):

You know you can look at the source of `DriverManager` to see how it loads `Driver` implementations from the classpath (the source is included in the JDK).

Or you can look at:

- [getConnection](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/sql/DriverManager.java#DriverManager.getConnection%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.util.Properties%2Cjava.lang.ClassLoader%29) (creates a connection)
- [loadInitialDrivers](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/sql/DriverManager.java#DriverManager.loadInitialDrivers%28%29) (loads the drivers from the `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` files in the classpath)

The `loadInitialDrivers` will ignore any exceptions thrown when iterating over the classes returned by the `ServiceLoader` iterator.

Also as `ClassNotFoundException` is a checked exception and `getConnection()` does not declare to throw it, you should have known it will never be able to throw that exception (unless wrapped in a different exception).